# Iterating over a symbolic `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm really not getting why tf keep on throwing this error:

> File "/var/folders/6f/83fhb735331g631bmd84c_xc0000gn/T/ipykernel_95896/2907429081.py", line 35, in call
> for _ in tf.range(10):
> Iterating over a symbolic `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.

I mean my code is the following:

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    ...
    def call(self, data, training=True, max_len=50):
        ...
        for _ in tf.range(10):
            ...

        return ...
```

The code where there are the `...` is useless pretty much, because it's that for loop that is causing this error (I can remove everything except that line and the error is still there)

Why I'm not allowed to do that for loop?

Using eager execution there is obviously no error, but that's not something that I would consider as a "fix"

Minimal reproducible example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
class MyModel1(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, input_text_processor, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.input_text_processor = input_text_processor
    def call(self, data, training=True, max_len=50):
        inputs = self.input_text_processor(data)
        for _ in tf.range(tf.shape(inputs)[1]):
            pass
        return []

    def train_step(self, data):
        self.call(data)
        return {"loss" : 0}
dataset = [
    "hi", "what's up", "what's the weather"
]
input_text_processor = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization()
input_text_processor.adapt(dataset)
with tf.device("/CPU:0"):
    model = MyModel1(input_text_processor)
    model.compile(tf.optimizers.Adam(), loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy())
    hist = model.fit(dataset, epochs=5)
```

If I run this, i get:

```
Epoch 1/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/ml/tensorflow-journey/39-rnn-enc-dec-attention/rnn-enc-dec-attention.py", line 23, in <module>
    hist = model.fit(dataset, epochs=5)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/ml-apple-metal-3-10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/ml-apple-metal-3-10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 1269, in autograph_handler
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: in user code:

    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/ml-apple-metal-3-10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/ml-apple-metal-3-10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1233, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/ml-apple-metal-3-10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/Users/username/ml/tensorflow-journey/39-rnn-enc-dec-attention/rnn-enc-dec-attention.py", line 13, in train_step
        self.call(data)
    File "/Users/username/ml/tensorflow-journey/39-rnn-enc-dec-attention/rnn-enc-dec-attention.py", line 8, in call
        for _ in tf.range(tf.shape(inputs)[1]):

    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Iterating over a symbolic `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

Comment: The `call` method is internally wrapped with a `tf.function` decorator.

Comment: @AloneTogether yes i know, but that should be allowed no? I mean it can be entirely evaluated a priori to build a graph on top of it

Comment: @AloneTogether that code comes for an attempt to build a attention based RNN, but I need to loop over the sequence in the decoder to perform the attention, so I'm pretty sure that there is a way to do some sort of for loop inside the call function... or should i put this code in the `train_step`? even though I don't think there is much difference, still a graph has to be built

Comment: what is your tf version

Comment: @AloneTogether `'2.11.0'`... however I'm on a M1 architecture, maybe that's relevant

Comment: @AloneTogether if you need I can post a MRE, so that you can test it on your machine

Comment: Hmm was not able to reproduce the error..

Comment: @AloneTogether thanks, I've posted a minimal reproducible example which only requires TF (i can see the same error on colab)

Comment: Thanks, just add `@tf.function` on top of `train_step` and it should be fine.

Comment: @AloneTogether you are right, please consider posting an answer and I'll mark it as correct